# Child Element not Same width as parent

Tags: html, css

This seems like a simple problem - I have the following html

```
    <div class="question" id="someQuestionId">
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="creation"/>
</div>
```

and the following CSS-

```
.creation{
    height:75%;
}
.creation,textarea{
    background-color:#F2FBEF;
}
.question{
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#0B3B24;


}
```

However, the width of the input box is less than that of the div within which it is contained - why is that occurring? I thought that the width should have been inherited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input` is an inline element (inline-block actually). It doesn't inherit its width from its parent, but has a browser-specific default width instead.

Change the CSS:

```
.creation{
    height:75%;
    /* Either: */
    width: 100%;
    /* or */
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Here's a cheatsheet for property inheritance: http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=2795d

Comment: ok, so I did the width:100%, now the input box is larger than its div tag - why is that happening?

Comment: `input` elements are `inline-block`, actually.

Comment: Because it may have a border, padding and/or margin. These are added to the width, I think. Making it a block is the easier option.

Comment: ok, I also tried display:block, and in that case the input box is smaller than the div - I need it to be the same width

Comment: also, I tried making width:150px, just to see what would happen and the input box is still larger than the div - it looks like I'm setting position:relative somewhere, but I'm not

Comment: Also with the fixed width, the additional width for border, margin and padding still applies. Read about the *box model*.

Comment: @lanzz That's right, but inline-block is actually just a 'special' inline element. It behaves the same regarding to inheriting width. Nevertheless I added a remark to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sure it is special, but that is relevant here: regular `inline` elements do not have a `width` property at all and always occupy just the space needed for their contents.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because browsers typically have their own default styles (width, padding, margin, etc.) that they give to certain DOM elements.  You should be using a CSS reset if you want to remove all these default browser styles.  You could also specifically specify the CSS your want for the input element.

Answer (score 0):

The input or any form element won't inherit the width of it's parent.

To make it the same width as it's parent you need too simply specify it's width, padding and border to match it's parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/24xd8/

```
<div>
 <input type="text" />
</div>​

div {
 width:150px;
 height:130px;
 padding-top:20px;
 background:#999;
}
input {
 width:138px;
 border:1px solid #000;
 padding:5px;
}
```